# Xamarin.Forms - Is there a way to disable android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize" in ContentPage

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have added `android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize"` in my App.xaml. But there are ContentPages where I don't like to have Resize keyboard because push all the layout over my keyboard.

Is it possible to disable it just of simple ContentPage?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following code in your ContentPage to restore this page to default:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;
...
    protected override void OnAppearing()
             {
                 base. OnAppearing();
                 App.Current.On<Android().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan);
             }
```

Comment: Wang-MSTF this Pan attribute will make the content page scrollable?

Comment: Yes, [WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.platformconfiguration.androidspecific.windowsoftinputmodeadjust?view=xamarin-forms) is Android's default behavior when keyboard is shown.